# Node.js: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm newer to cors and exactly what you need. I had an app working live a couple of months ago and it seems like it has broken due to CORS. Every time I make a request I get the error: "as been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Here is my server cors code:

```
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Set Port
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

// Listen
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);

// Load Middlewear
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json()); // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads

// CORS HEADERS MIDDLEWARE
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  }
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: You call `listen` twice there... that's suspicious. I'd try to fix that first.

Comment: removed still the same issue

Comment: Can you provide more detail? How exactly are you issuing the request? GET, POST, HEAD, other? With fetch, XHR, something else? From what browser? What's the exact error message? How are you accessing the server? Directly? Or behind some load-balancer, proxy, anything else?

Answer (score -1):

You need to allow the back to accept only by the front like this

``
var corsOptions = {
origin: 'http://localhost:8080' front ip or dns
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)
``

Comment: I added it and am still getting the same error, makes no sense